# суммирование времени PHP

Tags: php

Есть функция которая суммирует время, ответ выдает в формате "H:i:s", как сделать чтоб часы могли переваливать за 24 ?

```
function counter($time_1,$result)
{
global $result;
$secs = strtotime($time_1)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($result)+$secs);
return $result;
};
```

Comment: если часы будут переваливать за 24 то это уже не время

Comment: ну мне надо чтоб общее количество часов считал

Comment: какой итоговый результат вам необходим и в каком формате ?

Comment: 1233:23:23 можно и  1233 часов 23 минут 23 секунд

Comment: http://expange.ru/e/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B_(PHP) гляньте как тут реализовано может быть вам будет полезно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то надо получить разницу в часах

```
function counter($time, $modify = '+1 day') {
    $date = new DateTime($time);
    $date->modify($modify);
    $diff = $date->diff(new DateTime($time));
    $h = ($diff->days > 0 ? $diff->days * 24 : 0) + $diff->h;
    $i = $diff->i;
    $s = $diff->s;
    return "$h:$i:$s";
}
$time = "15.06.2018 13:32";
echo counter($time, '+5 day + 5 hours + 15 mins + 10 seconds');
```

Результат  125:15:10

Как то так

p.s.: Поправил потому что запихал strtotime

Comment: допустим у меня 12:23:23 ; 12:23:23 ; 12:23:23 и  тд времени как мне их плюсануть все чтоб обшие количество часов показывал. По идеи моя функация работает, но она ограничивается 24 часами, можно и дни там сделать, но мне надо чтоб количество часов было

Comment: Вон оно что=) Тогда проще

`function timeAdd($add, $time = "00:00:00") {
    list($h1, $i1, $s1, $h2, $i2, $s2) = explode(':', $time.":".$add);
    $s = $s1 + $s2;
    $i = $s > 59 ? intdiv($s, 60) : 0;
    $s = $s > 59 ? $s % 60 : $s;
    
    $i += $i1 + $i2;
    $h = $i > 59 ? intdiv($i, 60) : 0;
    $i = $i > 59 ? $i % 60 : $i;
    
    $h += $h1 + $h2;
    return "$h:$i:$s";
}`

Я просто не понял вопроса
$add это то что прибавиться к $time

Comment: А добавьте ещё `function timeAddMulti() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $start = "00:00:00";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($args); $i++)
        $start = timeAdd($args[$i], $start);
    return $start;
}`
И теперь можно передавать хоть сколько параметров например
$result = timeAddMulti("12:23:23", "12:23:23", "12:23:23", *** "12:23:23");

Comment: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/eI вот тут можно посмотреть